# I am trying to place an SVG file into a div, but sizing the SVG isn't working correctly

Tags: html, css, svg

Like the title says I am trying to load an SVG into a div, I have copied and pasted the code of the SVG into my HTML and then resized the div it is contained in. When I do this, the entire SVG changed to the size I have requested but there is "invisible padding" when I say this I mean the actual path isn't taking up the 250x250 px that I want.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>

  <div id="logo">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 804 804" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
      <clipPath id="_clip1">
        <path id="Artboard4" d="M804,402c0,-221.87 -180.13,-402 -402,-402c-221.87,0 -402,180.13 -402,402c0,221.87 180.13,402 402,402c221.87,0 402,-180.13 402,-402Z"/>
      </clipPath>
      <g clip-path="url(#_clip1)">
        <g>
          <path d="M381.924,101.027l-80.257,0c0,0 -80.386,-0.443 -80.256,80.257c0.129,80.7 0,120.385 0,120.385c0,0 0.414,80.104 80.256,80.257c79.843,0.152 -40.128,0 -40.128,0c0,0 -80.279,-0.283 -80.257,80.256c0.022,80.54 0,160.514 0,160.514c0,0 -0.382,80.211 80.257,80.256c80.639,0.046 120.385,0 120.385,0l0,-80.256l-80.257,0c0,0 -39.943,-0.666 -40.128,-40.129c-0.185,-39.463 0,-80.256 0,-80.256c0,0 0.089,-40.119 40.128,-40.129c40.04,-0.009 80.257,0 80.257,0l0,-160.513l-40.128,0c0,0 -40.318,-0.787 -40.129,-40.128c0.19,-39.341 0,-40.129 0,-40.129c0,0 0.398,-40.156 40.129,-40.128c39.73,0.028 40.128,0 40.128,0l0,-80.257Z" style="fill:#3c7abe;"/>
          <path d="M422.052,101.027l80.257,0c0,0 79.98,0.947 80.257,80.257c0.276,79.311 0,120.385 0,120.385c0,0 -0.689,79.91 -80.257,80.257c-79.568,0.347 40.128,0 40.128,0c0,0 80.204,1.599 80.257,80.256c0.053,78.658 0,240.77 0,240.77l-80.257,0l0,-200.641c0,0 -0.753,-40.321 -40.128,-40.129c-39.375,0.193 -80.257,0 -80.257,0l0,-160.513l40.129,0c0,0 39.387,-0.713 40.128,-40.128c0.741,-39.415 0,-40.129 0,-40.129c0,0 -0.679,-39.958 -40.128,-40.128c-39.45,-0.17 -40.129,0 -40.129,0l0,-80.257Z" style="fill:#3c7abe;"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>

</header>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#header {
width: 100%;
border: solid black 1px;
length: 2000px;
}

#logo {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: solid blue 5px;
}
```

Comment: what I can see is that the `clip-path` is making that padding, is it not?

Comment: @jackJoe If I give g in css padding of 0 it is still there though, surely that would get rid of it, if it was, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't really see the extra padding, can you make some kind of illustration please? also, what browser + version?

Comment: @jackJoe I have added an image, the blue border is the div and I want the logo inside to take up the whole div. I am using the latest version of chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this in 2 steps:

1. Remove `width="100%" height="100%"` from your `<svg>` element

Then, add the following styles to your stylesheet:

```
header svg {
position: relative;
top: -13%;
left: -13%;
width: 125%;
height: 125%;
}
```

**See:**

```css
#header {
width: 100%;
border: solid black 1px;
length: 2000px;
}

#logo {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: solid blue 5px;
}

header svg {
position: relative;
top: -13%;
left: -13%;
width: 125%;
height: 125%;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div id="logo">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 804 804" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
      <clipPath id="_clip1">
        <path id="Artboard4" d="M804,402c0,-221.87 -180.13,-402 -402,-402c-221.87,0 -402,180.13 -402,402c0,221.87 180.13,402 402,402c221.87,0 402,-180.13 402,-402Z"/>
      </clipPath>
      <g clip-path="url(#_clip1)">
        <g>
          <path d="M381.924,101.027l-80.257,0c0,0 -80.386,-0.443 -80.256,80.257c0.129,80.7 0,120.385 0,120.385c0,0 0.414,80.104 80.256,80.257c79.843,0.152 -40.128,0 -40.128,0c0,0 -80.279,-0.283 -80.257,80.256c0.022,80.54 0,160.514 0,160.514c0,0 -0.382,80.211 80.257,80.256c80.639,0.046 120.385,0 120.385,0l0,-80.256l-80.257,0c0,0 -39.943,-0.666 -40.128,-40.129c-0.185,-39.463 0,-80.256 0,-80.256c0,0 0.089,-40.119 40.128,-40.129c40.04,-0.009 80.257,0 80.257,0l0,-160.513l-40.128,0c0,0 -40.318,-0.787 -40.129,-40.128c0.19,-39.341 0,-40.129 0,-40.129c0,0 0.398,-40.156 40.129,-40.128c39.73,0.028 40.128,0 40.128,0l0,-80.257Z" style="fill:#3c7abe;"/>
          <path d="M422.052,101.027l80.257,0c0,0 79.98,0.947 80.257,80.257c0.276,79.311 0,120.385 0,120.385c0,0 -0.689,79.91 -80.257,80.257c-79.568,0.347 40.128,0 40.128,0c0,0 80.204,1.599 80.257,80.256c0.053,78.658 0,240.77 0,240.77l-80.257,0l0,-200.641c0,0 -0.753,-40.321 -40.128,-40.129c-39.375,0.193 -80.257,0 -80.257,0l0,-160.513l40.129,0c0,0 39.387,-0.713 40.128,-40.128c0.741,-39.415 0,-40.129 0,-40.129c0,0 -0.679,-39.958 -40.128,-40.128c-39.45,-0.17 -40.129,0 -40.129,0l0,-80.257Z" style="fill:#3c7abe;"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>

  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rounin, but the logo is still smaller than the div in your example, I would like the letters from the SVG to fill the entire div

Comment: I mistakenly wrote `#header` instead of `header` in the CSS. Try it again now.

Comment: That looks much better, thank you! If I inspect this with Chrome the actual SVG element is bigger than the div now, so that the letters fit the div, is that supposed to be like that? This is a screenshot of the inspect http://imgur.com/iQT5aq7

Comment: Yes, that's correct - all of the whitespace you can see when the SVG is 100% x 100% _is part of the SVG_. So, as I have demonstrated in the solution above, you have to make the SVG larger than 100% x 100% (revealed by the Chrome inspector) and then alter the SVG's relative position to compensate.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for accepting my solution.